# Spyder not finding an installed Python package

Tags: python, spyder

I have installed a package ("pulp") in Python311. Using Spyder, "import pulp" throws an message that pulp cannot be found. When I run the same program directly in the Python 3.11 installation, it finds the package.

Spyder's executable is set to "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe".

The Python IDE I am using directly is in C:/Program Files/Python311; more specifically, it is C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw

How can I get Spyder to find the libraries installed in this version?

Comment: What is the output from `import sys; sys.executable` in the Spyder console and the IDLE shell respectively?

Comment: I have finally got it working, thanks.